# Resource for proof that $SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$ has property T?

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, representation-theory

I'm looking for a proof that $SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$ has property $T$.  I believe the standard way to show this is that $SL_3(\mathbb{R})$ has it and that property T is inherited by lattices.  I've done some googling and the only online resource I've found is the Bekka, de la Harpe, and Valette book.  They prove it for any local field, and it's 11 or so pages plus things from the appendix, which from my experience reading other parts of the book is a lot of information.

I wanted to know if anyone had other suggestions for places to see different versions, or if most proofs are essentially the same length.

Comment: One part of the classical proof can be simplified: arxiv.org/abs/1611.00337.

Comment: Take a look at Part 4  in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/254b-notes-2-cayley-graphs-and-kazhdans-property-t/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I was also pointed to look at the proof in Brown/Ozawa.